# How do I map the return of my dataSource to a Kendo AutoComplete UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, autocomplete, telerik

I have a Kendo jquery AutoComplete UI component with a remote REST web API dataSource. I want to map the responce of the API to the autoComplete. I have it displaying the choices but when I examine the select function I just see what I've selected. What I want is the complete json object on the select event. Or at least what I really need is the unitKey property.

my code:

```
//create AutoComplete UI component
    $("#autoAddress").kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        dataTextField: "address",                
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Address lookup ...",            
        select : function(e) {
            var item = e.item;
            console.log(item.text());
        },
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource ({   
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://testapi.mydomain.com/homeinfo/api/address/",
                    // dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        q : function() {
                            return $("#autoAddress").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                        },                                
                        maxRows: 30
                    }
                }
            },
            schema : {
                data: function(response){
                    return response;
                }
            }                              
        })
    });
```

sample date from api call:

```
[
    {
        "unitKey": "S37.75      ",
        "address": "1234 ADDISON AVE"
    },
    {
        "unitKey": "S22.215     ",
        "address": "1234 AUGUSTINE DR"
    },
    {
        "unitKey": "L100.9      ",
        "address": "1234 AVENIDA DE LAS CASAS"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get the "unitKey" when the user makes a selection from the autocomplete component.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at e.dataItem rather than e.item:

```
console.log(e.dataItem.unitKey);
```

In cases like this I usually log 'e' itself to the console or breakpoint with the debugger to inspect it to see what it contains since the documentation is not always as comprehensive as it could be.